# SQL Pivot Time Table Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server

For insight in vehicle rental versus vehicle occupancy / empty times, i want to create a time matrix (for use in a SSAS Cube).

Below the available data for the rental part:

[image]

Now i would like to pivot this data to the following result. Showing the amount of minutes for vehicle rental per hour.

[image]

Any help on the correct SQL syntax to achieve this result would be great.

Comment: Why the first row for hour 08:00 has minutes 5? can you explain how minutes should be calculated from `starttime` and endtime?

Comment: The vehicle starttime is 8:55, so for the first 55 minutes in the 8th hour there is no rental. only the last 5 minutes within 8 are rental minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use CTE to collect 24 hours and use a `CASE` to achieve your expected result like this:

```
;WITH HoursAll(H) AS (
    SELECT 0 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT H + 1
    FROM HoursAll
    WHERE H < 23
)
SELECT t.date, t.vehicle, CAST((CAST(ha.H As varchar(10)) + ':00') As time) as [hour]
    , CASE 
        WHEN ha.H = DATEPART(HOUR,t.starttime) THEN 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.starttime)
        WHEN ha.H = DATEPART(HOUR,t.endtime) THEN DATEPART(MINUTE,t.endtime)
        ELSE 60
    END
FROM HoursAll ha
JOIN yourTable t ON ha.H BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR,t.starttime) AND DATEPART(HOUR,t.endtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetTime (@Start TIME, @End TIME)
RETURNS @TableTime TABLE(_HH TIME, _MM INT)
AS
BEGIN
   WHILE DATEPART(HH, @Start) <= DATEPART(HH, @End)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @TableTime
      SELECT DATEPART(HH, @Start), 60
      SET @Start = CAST(DATEADD(HH,1,@Start) AS TIME)
   END
   UPDATE @TableTime SET _MM = 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, @Start) WHERE _HH = DATEPART(HH, @Start)
   UPDATE @TableTime SET _MM = DATEPART(MINUTE, @End) WHERE _HH = DATEPART(HH, @End)
END


SELECT DATE, VEHICLE CROSS APPLY GetTime(Starttime, Endtime) G
```